# Removing shortcut overlay icon from symlinks only

Tags: windows-7, icons, symbolic-link

I have recently started using symlinks to organise my folders on my PC but I do not like the Windows shortcut icon overlaying the link.

[image: Symlink shortcut icon overlay]

I have seen tutorials for removing the icon from shortcuts (I imagine this will also apply to symlinks but admittedly have not tried it yet). However these tutorials remove the overlay icon from ALL shortcuts; I only want to perform it on specific links (symlinks and not actual shortucts).

Comment: Those icon overlays [can be customized](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html#customoverlayicons). You could hide/change those associated with symbolic links and directory junctions while keeping the regular shortcuts ones.